# How to avoid filter to a specific http request in Play with Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have two filters in my Play!WithScala application.

```
object Filter1 extends Filter { ... }

object Filter2 extends Filter { ... }

object Global extends WithFilters(Filter1, Filter2)
```

I want Filter2 not to be applied to a specific http request, say with URL '/abc'. Is there a generic and easy way of doing this, instead of writing conditions in the Filter2.

I am using Play2.2 and Scala 2.10

Answer (score 2):

Follow [the docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaHttpFilters):

*In contrast (to filters), [action composition](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaActionsComposition) is intended for route specific concerns, such as authentication and authorisation, caching and so on. If your filter is not one that you want applied to every route, consider using action composition instead, it is far more powerful. And don’t forget that you can create your own action builders that compose your own custom defined sets of actions to each route, to minimise boilerplate.*

Comment: Thanks alot for this. Unfortunately, I am not in position to refactor my code to add a custom action builder/action; But is there a way to avoid a filter simply for one particular route (Like how we do in Spring)?